# Move a borderless form with a picturebox control

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I have a winform with no border.  I added a picturebox control to it and set it to Dock in parent container.  I want to do 2 thing, when I click anywhere in the picturebox I want to be able to drag the whole form anywhere on the screen and  would like to be able to resize the form by dragging the botton right hand corner.

I am able to do the above if I just have the form but since the picturebox fills the whole form Im not sure how to do it.

The code that makes the form work:

```
    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
    private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref message);

        if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)message.Result == HTCLIENT)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;

            int x = (int)(message.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
            int y = (int)((message.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            Point pt = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
            Size clientSize = ClientSize;
            if (pt.X >= clientSize.Width - 16 && pt.Y >= clientSize.Height - 16 && clientSize.Height >= 16)
            {
                message.Result = (IntPtr)(IsMirrored ? htBottomLeft : htBottomRight);
                return;
            }

        }


   }
```

Comment: Have you tried handling the WM_NCHITTEST yourself?

Comment: Yes.  If I just have the form it works, when I add the picturebox it doesnt.

Comment: I think what you may need to do is override a picturebox and handle the nchittest of the picturebox also (possibly hittest too?) Edit: i dont have an example of how to do this at the minute but if you take a look at the picturebox hierarchy you'll see it handles the [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) too

Comment: Just don't use a picture box.  If you want to display an image then use the form's BackgroundImage property.